# Elements getting far from each other after changing viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive, element

please can somenone help me with this responsive problem. After changing viewport my header and main elements are going far from each other. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzfx3d6g/)

```
<header>
  <div class="slider">
    <img src="picture1" alt=""> 
   <img src="picture2" alt="" >
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <h1>Hello Hello</h1>
</main>
```

CSS

```
 body{
      margin:0;
    }

.slider{
  height: 36em; 
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;  
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

main{
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}
```

Comment: whats the goal?

Comment: my goal is when i change mentioned viewport my elements (header and main) will keep same margin (distance) from each other. If i need to rewrite it all its ok, but please show me some way how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you set a fixed height

```
.slider{
  height: 36em; // <-- HERE
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

So when the screen decreases, the image decreases too, and the `.slider` keeps the same height

Just remove this fixed height and change it to `max-height`, case the image needs to be absolute, you'll need to calculate the slide's height manually with javascript

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzfx3d6g/3/)

**Javascript** with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $('.slider img').height();
    $('.slider').height(height);
});
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  margin:0;
}

.slider{
  max-height: 36em; 
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;  
  top:0;
  left:0;width:100%;
}

main{
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="slider">
    <img src="http://www.freewalkertours.com/rio/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/04/o-que-fazer-no-rio-de-janeiro-cristo.jpg" alt=""> 
   <img src="https://mmoexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sw352356.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <h1>Hello Hello</h1>
</main>
```